# insert some tuples into table in web2py

Tags: mysql, csv, web2py

I want to import csv file into auth_user table without duplicate username，so I create table user

```
db.define_table('user',
                Field('username',unique=True,length=255),
                Field('password'))
```

import csv file into user then compare table user and auth_user, insert some records that in user table while not in auth_user table.

```
db.executesql('insert into auth_user(username,password) select username,password from user where not exists(select * from auth_user where (auth_user.username=user.username))')
```

it doesn't work, so I don't know how to insert selected tuples into auth_user table.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, passwords are hashed when inserted into the `auth_user` table (via a form validator associated with the password field). So, you don't want to do a standard SQL insert of the plain text passwords into the table (not only is that insecure, but subsequent attempts at login will fail because `Auth` is expecting hashed passwords).

The easiest way to have the hashing done when doing bulk inserts is to loop through the records and insert each one using the `.validate_and_insert` method. This will run all of the field validators (which will result in the passwords being hashed), and any records that fail validation will simply not be inserted (so, for example, a duplicate username will not be inserted because it will fail validation).

```
for user in db(db.user).select():
    db.auth_user.validate_and_insert(username=user.username, password=user.password)
```

Although the validation process will automatically reject any duplicate usernames, if you expect a lot of duplicates and want to improve efficiency, you can first select only the non-duplicates from the `user` table:

```
users = db(~db.user.username.belongs(db()._select(db.auth_user.username))).select()
for user in users:
    db.auth_user.validate_and_insert(username=user.username, password=user.password)
```

Also, note that by default, the `auth_user` table does require values in the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` fields (and a valid email address is needed for some of the `Auth` functionality, such as resetting the password). So, you should either plan to fill in those fields as well, or otherwise set their `requires` attributes to `None` so validation does not fail. For example:

```
db.auth_user.first_name.requires = None
```

Another option is to define a custom `auth_user` table.

Comment: so wonderful! thanks a million！I have found that so I want to encrypt the password field in csv file with microsoft excel.while the answer above is so wonderful!Thanks again！

Answer (score 1):

Try to cghange your use of subselect:

```
insert into auth_user(username,password) select username,password from user 
where UserName not in (select username from auth_user where   
(auth_user.username=user.username))'
```

Comment: I hava another question,the users that inserted by csv file can't login in.Do you know why? Many thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help.That other thing is probably infulenced with something else. Look wath you have in table left. And can you please accept my answer as correct. Thanks.