# the users that insert by importing csv file can't login in in web2py

Tags: csv, web2py

I insert users into auth_user table with csv file that include two fields username and password.
users have been inserted into auth_user table successfully，but I can't use username and password to login in. the registration_key is null.why the users can't login in?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326602/440323). Answer copied below:

By default, passwords are hashed when inserted into the `auth_user` table (via a form validator associated with the password field). So, you don't want to do a standard SQL insert of the plain text passwords into the table (not only is that insecure, but subsequent attempts at login will fail because `Auth` is expecting hashed passwords).

The easiest way to have the hashing done when doing bulk inserts is to loop through the records and insert each one using the `.validate_and_insert` method. This will run all of the field validators (which will result in the passwords being hashed), and any records that fail validation will simply not be inserted (so, for example, a duplicate username will not be inserted because it will fail validation).

```
for user in db(db.user).select():
    db.auth_user.validate_and_insert(username=user.username, password=user.password)
```

Although the validation process will automatically reject any duplicate usernames, if you expect a lot of duplicates and want to improve efficiency, you can first select only the non-duplicates from the `user` table:

```
users = db(~db.user.username.belongs(db()._select(db.auth_user.username))).select()
for user in users:
    db.auth_user.validate_and_insert(username=user.username, password=user.password)
```

Also, note that by default, the `auth_user` table does require values in the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` fields (and a valid email address is needed for some of the `Auth` functionality, such as resetting the password). So, you should either plan to fill in those fields as well, or otherwise set their `requires` attributes to `None` so validation does not fail. For example:

```
db.auth_user.first_name.requires = None
```

Another option is to define a custom `auth_user` table.

Comment: so wonderful! thanks a million！I have found that so I want to encrypt the password field in csv file with microsoft excel.while the answer above is so wonderful!Thanks again！